# Can I install a Joomla Component from another component

Tags: installation, joomla, auto-update

Does the Joomla framework provide functionality to programmers to install an extension from another extension? I mean a full joomla extension and not an extension to a component (such as a plugin for a particular component).

The purpose is to create an update tool that checks versions and updates extensions. It would be particularly handy for managing multiple websites.

A similar extension is the Admin Tools component from Akeeba. It can check for updates, and do the updates on Joomla. It's not GPL so I probably am not allowed to enhance their component with the desired functionality and then use it commercially, but that's for later concern.

Any suggestions or thought directions? =]

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge I don't think they provide the functionality, however you should be free to download files with fopen/curl and copy them all over the place as you want. Joomla also doesn't check if where you copy files is actually within a specific component space.

On GPL and commercial, there is no link between commercial and GPL - you just have to distribute  the source code whenever you distribute, even if you charge for it or the access. This means everyone down the chain is free to pass your code on for free.